# send a email notification everytime a formula field is changed except for the first time edit

Tags: email, workflow, email-alert, workflowrule

I need to send a email notification when a formula field changes except for the first time.

I have a workflow rule setup to evaluate every time the record is changed and setup rule criteria "ISCHANGED(field name).

what is the best way i can implement to avoid the first time email alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Formula fields have no stored value - their values are calculated at the time of accessing the data. There is no change event to which you can react for formula fields.

You'd need to build your automation to react to changes to the fields that themselves drive the value of your formula field.

You could potentially implement "ignoring the first change" by setting a checkbox field on the object the first time your automation is invoked. Then, send your notifications only when the field is true.

Comment: Instead i used a Workflow rule to update the total on the field. Now its just a Number field.